# How to get link using simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Html document is like this

```
<li><h2><a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma">Beezfeed</h2></a></li>
<li><a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma/kuto">Beezfeed kuto</a></li>
<li><a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma/movies">Beezfeed movies</a></li>
```

Here I want the last two link href. Here is my code I am using simple html dom, so please answer me on this and can you please tell me in regex also.

```
$bb->load($str);
$link = $bb->find('div[class=azindex] li');

foreach ($link as $s) {
    $lin = $s->find("a");
    foreach ($lin as $li) {
        echo $li->href . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

I get all the link containing in li tag, But I do not want link that has h2 tag. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can go for regular expression, I don't know it but your task done by regex.

Comment: Please try $links = $bb->find(''li > a');

Comment: Can you please tell me regex expression for this, any ways thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @ManishJangir i've tried, it, for some reason, get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had to do it in a simple way i would do it like this :

```
$bb->load($str);
$link=$bb->find('div[class=azindex] li');
foreach($link as $s){
$lin=$s->find("a");
foreach($lin as $li){
    if(is_null($li->find("h2")) {
        echo $li->href."<br>";
    }
    /*Do nothing if h2 was found*/
}
}
```

I just used the find method on the $li, if a h2 is found i do nothing, otherwise i print the line.
I could not test it, i hope it helps a little.

Comment: Can you please tell me regex expression for this, any ways thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

A regex to match the correct links:

```
$items = '
<li><h2><a href="http://beezfeed1.cu.ma">Beezfeed1</h2></a></li>
<li><p><a href="http://beezfeed2.cu.ma/">Beezfeed2</a></p></li>
<li><h4><a href="http://beezfeed3.cu.ma">Beezfeed3</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="http://beezfeed4.cu.ma/">Beezfeed4</a></li>
';

preg_match_all('(<li>(?!<h[1-9]>).*<a href="(.*)")',$items,$matches);
```

this matches:
**http//beezfeed2.cu.ma/** and **http//beezfeed4.cu.ma/**

this will match all h1 to h9 tags.

more strict matches:

```
preg_match_all('(<li>\s?<a href="(.*)")',$items,$matches);
```

this only returns:

**http//beezfeed4.cu.ma**

This regex doesn't allow any characters between <li> and the <a> except spaces(\s? is optional space).